# Using serde to deserialize a HashMap with a Enum key

Tags: rust, serde, toml

I have the following Rust code which models a configuration file which includes a `HashMap` keyed with an `enum`.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
enum Source {
    #[serde(rename = "foo")]
    Foo,
    #[serde(rename = "bar")]
    Bar
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SourceDetails {
    name: String,
    address: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    name: String,
    main_source: Source,
    sources: HashMap<Source, SourceDetails>,
}

fn main() {
    let config_str = std::fs::read_to_string("testdata.toml").unwrap();
    match toml::from_str::<Config>(&config_str) {
        Ok(config) => println!("toml: {:?}", config),
        Err(err) => eprintln!("toml: {:?}", err),
    }

    let config_str = std::fs::read_to_string("testdata.json").unwrap();
    match serde_json::from_str::<Config>(&config_str) {
        Ok(config) => println!("json: {:?}", config),
        Err(err) => eprintln!("json: {:?}", err),
    }
}
```

This is the Toml representation:

```
name = "big test"
main_source = "foo"

[sources]
foo = { name = "fooname", address = "fooaddr" }

[sources.bar]
name = "barname"
address = "baraddr"
```

This is the JSON representation:

```json
{
  "name": "big test",
  "main_source": "foo",
  "sources": {
    "foo": {
      "name": "fooname",
      "address": "fooaddr"
    },
    "bar": {
      "name": "barname",
      "address": "baraddr"
    }
  }
}
```

Deserializing the JSON with `serde_json` works perfectly, but deserializing the Toml with `toml` gives the error.

```
Error: Error { inner: ErrorInner { kind: Custom, line: Some(5), col: 0, at: Some(77), message: "invalid type: string \"foo\", expected enum Source", key: ["sources"] } }
```

If I change the `sources` `HashMap` to be keyed on `String` instead of `Source`, both the JSON and the Toml deserialize correctly.

I'm pretty new to serde and toml, so I'm looking for suggestions on how to I would properly de-serialize the toml variant.

Comment: The TOML format supports only strings as keys. And because of that the `toml-rs` library only supports string keys,  but your have a `Source` enum as key, which is not a valid TOML: https://github.com/alexcrichton/toml-rs/issues/212

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I find it disappointing that this use isn't supported, considering JSON keys are also strings by-definition and they are able to support enums. At least there's a reasonable workaround provided in that issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68579809/rust-advice-on-using-serde-to-deserialize-a-hashmap-with-a-enum-key/68580953#comment121200639_68579809), the Toml deserializer [doesn't support enums as keys](https://github.com/alexcrichton/toml-rs/issues/212).

You can use `serde` attributes to convert them to `String` first:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
#[serde(try_from = "String")]
enum Source {
    Foo,
    Bar
}
```

And then implement a conversion from `String`:

```
struct SourceFromStrError;

impl fmt::Display for SourceFromStrError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        f.write_str("SourceFromStrError")
    }
}

impl TryFrom<String> for Source {
    type Error = SourceFromStrError;
    fn try_from(s: String) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match s.as_str() {
            "foo" => Ok(Source::Foo),
            "bar" => Ok(Source::Bar),
            _ => Err(SourceFromStrError),
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you only need this for the `HashMap` in question, you could also follow the suggestion in the Toml issue, which is to keep the definition of `Source` the same and use the crate, [`serde_with`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_with), to modify how the `HashMap` is serialized instead:

```
use serde_with::{serde_as, DisplayFromStr};
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    name: String,
    main_source: Source,
    #[serde_as(as = "HashMap<DisplayFromStr, _>")]
    sources: HashMap<Source, SourceDetails>,
}
```

This requires a `FromStr` implementation for `Source`, rather than `TryFrom<String>`:

```
impl FromStr for Source {
    type Err = SourceFromStrError;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
       match s {
            "foo" => Ok(Source::Foo),
            "bar" => Ok(Source::Bar),
            _ => Err(SourceFromStrError),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using `try_from = "String"` worked perfect. I also added `into = "String"` and implemented `Into<String>` so that serializing also works.