# How to use serde to serialize/deserialize a HashMap with enum keys that contain data?

Tags: serialization, rust, hashmap, deserialization, serde

I need to serialize and deserialize a HashMap, `h`, with enum `Foo` as a key to and from JSON. `Foo`'s variants contain data (here simplified to `u32`, but actually are enums themselves):

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use serde_json;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Foo {
  A(u32),
  B(u32),
}

// Tried several different things here! Just deriving the relevant traits doesn't work.
struct Bar {
  h: HashMap<Foo, i32>, // The i32 value type is arbitrary
}

fn main() {
  let mut bar = Bar { h: HashMap::new() };
  bar.h.insert(Foo::A(0), 1);

  // I want to be able to do this
  let bar_string = serde_json::to_string(&bar).unwrap();
  let bar_deser: Bar = serde_json::from_str(&bar_string).unwrap();
}
```

Since the JSON specification requires keys to be strings I know I need to customise the way serialization and deserialization are done for `Foo` when it is a key in `h`. I've tried the following:

- Custom implementations of Serialize and Deserialize (e.g. in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276896/how-do-i-use-serde-to-serialize-a-hashmap-with-structs-as-keys-to-json))
- Serde attributes e.g.: `#[serde(into = "String", try_from = "String")]` + implementing `Into<String> for Foo` and `TryFrom<String> for Foo` (described in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68579809/using-serde-to-deserialize-a-hashmap-with-a-enum-key))
- Using the 'serde_with' crate (also described in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68579809/using-serde-to-deserialize-a-hashmap-with-a-enum-key)).

Unfortunately none of these have worked - all eventually failed with different panics after compiling successfully.

What is a good way to achieve what I want in serde, if there is one? If not, I'd be very grateful for any workaround suggestions.

Bonus question: why doesn't serde/serde_json provide a default serialization to a `String` + deserialization of an enum like `Foo` when it is used as a key in a `HashMap`?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your current example has several errors. It is missing a `main`, `serde:json` should be `serde_json`, the `HashMap` `use` statement is missing, a `;` is missing in the first line.

Comment: I have a feeling that solving this will involve writing your own implementation of `Serialize` and `Deserialize`

Comment: Thanks @Finomnis I've updated the code as per your comment. Next time I'll make sure it runs (first time posting here!).

Comment: In future you can double-check if it runs by implementing it in https://play.rust-lang.org/ ;)

Comment: `main` is missing a `()`

Comment: `Foo` is missing `derive` for `Hash`, `Eq` and `PartialEq` to be storable in a `HashMap`.

Please implement your code in https://play.rust-lang.org/ until you get the exact error message you were describing.

Comment: @jonasbb Yes, it would have helped a lot - thanks! Somehow it never found it while searching before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working solution with `serde_as` from the `serde_with` helper crate:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Hash, Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Foo {
    A(u32),
    B(u32),
}

#[serde_with::serde_as]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Bar {
    #[serde_as(as = "HashMap<serde_with::json::JsonString, _>")]
    h: HashMap<Foo, i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar = Bar { h: HashMap::new() };
    bar.h.insert(Foo::A(0), 1);

    let bar_string = serde_json::to_string(&bar).unwrap();
    let bar_deser: Bar = serde_json::from_str(&bar_string).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", bar);
    println!("{}", bar_string);
    println!("{:?}", bar_deser);
}
```

```
Bar { h: {A(0): 1} }
{"h":{"{\"A\":0}":1}}
Bar { h: {A(0): 1} }
```

---

> Bonus question: why doesn't serde/serde_json provide a default serialization to a String + deserialization of an enum like Foo when it is used as a key in a HashMap?

If you noticed, most of those problems become runtime errors.

That is because `serde` actually [*does* have a representation of a map](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/trait.Serializer.html#tymethod.serialize_map) that works with all Rust values. So `serde` itself has no power over this problem.

The problem comes when `serde_json` tries to feed the map into a json `Serializer`. And yes, this serializer could indeed convert any key into a JSON string and back if that was implemented.

I think it's more of a design decision why this isn't done. If JSON only supports string keys, so should the JSON serializer. If the user wants to use other types as keys, he should convert them to strings first as seen in the code example above.

Comment: Thanks very much @Finomnis for the code and the explanation of the 'bonus' question, very much appreciated!